# Moving Child nodes from a XML file to Parent using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file as below.
CONTROLHOLDER is a Parent and it can have child CONTROLHOLDER inside it to nth level. 
But i want to take out all such childs CONTROLHOLDER and its content and place it below the Parent CONTROLHOLDER as a parent.
Let me know the best recommended way for this

```
<CONTROLS>
<CONTROLHOLDER ID="CH1">
    <CONTROL11 ID="ED1">        
    <CONTROL11>
    <CONTROL12 ID="ED2">
    </CONTROL12>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH2">
    <CONTROL21 ID="ED3">        
    <CONTROL21>
    <CONTROL22 ID="ED4">
    </CONTROL22>
        <CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH21">
            <CONTROL211 ID="ED5" >  
            <CONTROL211>
            <CONTROL212 ID="ED6" >
            </CONTROL212>
        </CONTROLHOLDER>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH3">
    <CONTROL31 ID="ED31">   
    <CONTROL31>
    <CONTROL32 ID="ED32">
    </CONTROL32>
        <CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH31">
            <CONTROL311 ID= "ED311">
            <CONTROL311>
            <CONTROL312 ID= "ED312">
            </CONTROL312>
                <CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH313">
                    <CONTROL3131 ID= "ED3131">
                    <CONTROL3131>
                    <CONTROL3132 ID= "ED3132">
                    </CONTROL3132>
                </CONTROLHOLDER>
        </CONTROLHOLDER>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
```

Need to convert to

```
<CONTROLS>
<CONTROLHOLDER ID="CH1">
    <CONTROL11 ID="ED1">        
    <CONTROL11>
    <CONTROL12 ID="ED2">
    </CONTROL12>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH2">
    <CONTROL21 ID="ED3">    
    <CONTROL21>
    <CONTROL22 ID="ED4">
    </CONTROL22>    
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH21">
    <CONTROL211 ID="ED5" >
    <CONTROL211>
    <CONTROL212 ID="ED6" >
    </CONTROL212>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH3">
    <CONTROL31 ID="ED31">   
    <CONTROL31>
    <CONTROL32 ID="ED32">
    </CONTROL32>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH31">
    <CONTROL311 ID= "ED311">
    <CONTROL311>
    <CONTROL312 ID= "ED312">
    </CONTROL312>           
</CONTROLHOLDER>
<CONTROLHOLDER  ID= "CH313">
    <CONTROL3131 ID= "ED3131">
    <CONTROL3131>
    <CONTROL3132 ID= "ED3132">
    </CONTROL3132>
</CONTROLHOLDER>
```

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed, by the way. You have opening tags where there should be closing tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off with the Identity Template to handle the copy of existing nodes

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you say you want a template to move child nodes, the **CONTROLHOLDER** elements, to their parent. Well, just have a template matching **CONTROLHOLDER** where you copy it, and all its children apart from other **CONTROLHOLDER** elements. For any such child elements, copy these after the copy for the parent, like so

```
<xsl:template match="CONTROLHOLDER">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::CONTROLHOLDER)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTROLHOLDER" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note this template is recursive, so all **CONTROLHOLDER** will 'bubble up' to be under the main root element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="CONTROLHOLDER">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::CONTROLHOLDER)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTROLHOLDER" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is good. Just to add a scenario. If i got another ControlHolder type, For Example ControlHolderTypeA and ControlHolderTypeB and incase if i find any one of them i want to move it out from Inside the Parent what will be the way to go. Just a note ControlHolderTypeB can be child of ControlHolderTypeA and vise Versa.

Comment: Never Mind. I got answer to the revised question

Comment: Hello Tim, actually when i have 2 category of ControlHolder(ControlHolderTypeA and ControlHolderTypeB ) and presuming ControlHolderTypeA can be inside ControlHolderTypeB and vise versa, this does not work.

Comment: If you are referring to element names, try replacing any occurrence of `CONTROLHOLDER` in the XSLT with either `CONTROLHOLDERA|CONTROLHOLDERB`, or `not(self::CONTROLHOLDERA) and not(self::CONTROLHOLDERB)`. If you can't work it out, it would be best to ask a whole new question about it here on StackOverflow. Thanks!