# Convert All Child nodes as siblings using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my example xml

```
<p> Heading </p>
<footnote>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>
      <i>
        This is all usually in footnote
      </i>
    </b>
 </p>
 <p ahref="www.google.com"> More can be googled </p>
</footnote>
```

Usually this data is itself displayed on page . However I want to apply a xslt where all this data is showed in column of a table and the footnote is messing things for me.

How can I in XSLT take all children on `footnote` in this case three `<p>`(could be anything also just not p tag) and move them as sibling to footnote and then delete footnote.

I saw a similar example but here [Moving Child nodes from a XML file to Parent using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788711/moving-child-nodes-from-a-xml-file-to-parent-using-xslt) but this is to move them by each element name . In my case anything can be inside footnote. Also I want to move along ahref and any other attibutes as well.

final expected outcome

```
<p> Heading </p>
</p>
<p>
  <b>
    <i>
     This is all usually in footnote
    </i>
   </b>
</p>
<p ahref="www.google.com"> More can be googled </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do simply like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Remove footnote and copy children -->
  <xsl:template match="footnote">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZB/1

Comment: That was easy . I overcomplicated it being a novice with xslt